# SqlCeCommand Parameters not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact database and I'm trying to insert a record into it using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. This method worked perfectly fine in another project, but it doesn't work now.

```
private void AddNewProfile() {
    try {
        using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString)) {
            using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand()) {
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profiles (ProfileName, ProfilePath, ProfileDescription) VALUES ('@name', '@path', '@desc');";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "New Profile";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "C:\\";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "A blank profile.";

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

The problem comes in with the parameters - I practically copied the code from one of my other projects, but it doesn't work correctly. Instead of executing this:

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (ProfileName, ProfilePath, ProfileDescription) 
VALUES ('New Profile', 'C:\\', 'A blank profile.');
```

it executes this:

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (ProfileName, ProfilePath, ProfileDescription) 
VALUES ('@name', '@path', '@desc');
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

Firstly, your SQL is specifying *literal* values because of the quotes. It should be:

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (ProfileName, ProfilePath, ProfileDescription)
VALUES (@name, @path, @desc)
```

That way the SQL refers to the parameters, rather than literals with values of `"@name", "@path" and "@desc".

(I've removed the unnecessary semi-colon as well.)

Secondly, calling `AddWithValue`, but providing the *type* as the value, then overwriting the value. That's pointless and confusing - the type you're specifying is going to be lost. You should be using:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "New Profile";
```

Finally, you don't need to call `conn.Close()` - it's already in a `using` statement... and you can pass `conn` to the `SqlCeCommand` constructor, to make things slightly simpler.

Comment: That's seriously it? I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use single quotes when you declare your parameters. With single quotes, SQL will recognize them as a *[string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)* not parameters. Just use them in your `SqlCommand` like;

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (ProfileName, ProfilePath, ProfileDescription)
       VALUES (@name, @path, @desc)
```

Also you are using [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a wrong way. It doesn't need the *type*.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "New Profile");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", "C:\\");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", "A blank profile.");
```

or you can use [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to declare their types like;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "New Profile";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@path", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "C:\\";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@desc", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "A blank profile.");
```

And your `conn.Close();` is redundant. The [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) will take care of it for you. Under the hood, `SqlConnection.Dispose()` calls the `SqlConnection.Close()` method.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:** You are enclosig the parameters (@name, @path, @desc) within single quotes, so that you are passing the values as `@name, @path, @desc` .

**Solution 1:** You should not enclose the Parameters within single quotes while using Parameterised queries.

Replace This:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profiles (ProfileName, ProfilePath, 
       ProfileDescription)  VALUES ('@name', '@path', '@desc');";
```

With This:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profiles 
    (ProfileName, ProfilePath, ProfileDescription) 
                     VALUES (@name, @path, @desc);";
```

**Problem 2:** you need to provide both parameter name and its value to the `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method

**Solution 2:**

Replace This:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "New Profile";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "C:\\";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", SqlDbType.Text).Value = "A blank profile.";
```

With This:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name","New Profile");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path","C:\\");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc","A blank profile.");
```

**Complete Code:**

```
private void AddNewProfile() {
 try {
        using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString)) {
        using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand()) {
         cmd.Connection = conn;

         cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profiles (ProfileName, ProfilePath, 
                         ProfileDescription) VALUES (@name,@path, @desc);";
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name","New Profile");
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path","C:\\");
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc","A blank profile.");
         conn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();             
        }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```